# Make changes in node library

Tags: react-native, npm, node-modules

i am working with React Native and there are several packages like react-native-fetch-blob, react-native-photo-view and other that for release build require higher version of SDK, that the one that they are installed with.

Everytime i reinstall the node_modules and i am making a new build after that i have to change these settings manualy to be higher and to match those in the main build.gradle file that i have.

Is there any way that i can save these settings in these libraries so i don't have to change them manually every time i am making a new release build ?

Answer (score 0):

[patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) lets you instantly make and keep fixes to npm dependencies

install patch-package with npm or yarn, then make changes you want on specific package then run:

> npx patch-package some-package

finally commit your changes